# Bind different events to multiple HTML elements, but perform one function

Tags: javascript, bind, jquery

I have a `button`, a `div` and a `select combo-box`

I want to execute a particular function on **click of the button**, **on mouseenter in div** and **onchange and blur of the combobox**

I do this right now

```
$("#divID").bind('mouseenter',function(){

   // do my stuff
}) 

$("#comboID").bind('blur change',function(){

   // do my stuff
})  

$("#buttonID").bind('click',function(){

   // do my stuff
})
```

I do the same stuff everytime. I want to combine all the events together to avoid duplication is there a way to bind each one of the elements with specific events in one statement

I know I can write the code in a separate `function` and call it each time(solves duplication).

But I want to know can this be done without a separate `function` and only `jQuery`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have seprate event with seprate selectors so one selector or event is not enough, you can map ids and events. I think jquery could not help much to make it single statment.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ReRBe/1/)**

```
arrIDs = ['divID','comboID','buttonID'];
arrEvents = ['mouseenter','blur change','click'];

for(idx=0; idx < arrIDs.length; idx++) 
    $("#" + arrIDs[idx] ).bind(arrEvents[idx], yourFunction);

function yourFunction(event)
{
    alert("yourFunction call by " + event.target.id);  
}
```

Comment: Excellent...But still(logically) the binding statement is executed trice....Is there any jQuery api that would allow all of it in a single compound statement....

Comment: jquery also executes these kind of operation repeadely but hidden from us.

Answer (score 1):

Not in one statement, since you want to attach different events to different elements. But you can declare a single callback-function that you call for all events.

```
var callback = function () {
  // do my stuff
};

$("#divID").bind('mouseenter', callback);
$("#comboID").bind('blur change', callback);
$("#buttonID").bind('click', callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use jquery you can always set set the other events to be equal to the first.. but good practice will be creating a separate function